# How do I allow different amounts of input in c++

Tags: c++

Assume all variables exist (didnt bother declaring them all here)

```
  if(input=='R') goto restart;
  if(input=='X') exit(0);
  if(input=='D') moveRight(edgeLength, board, score);
  if(input=='S') moveDown(edgeLength,board, arrSize);
  if(input=='A') moveLeft(edgeLength,board, arrSize);
  if(input=='W') moveUp(edgeLength,arrSize,board);
  if(input=='P')
  {
      cin>> number>>position;
     board[position]=number;
  }
```

This input is put into a loop, so the user is asked for input so long as this game is in play.
My goal is to allow for input such as

```
p 3 50
```

to place the number 50 at index position 3.

With my current code, I have to type 'p' press enter, then the next two numbers. 
However, id like the program to detect '`p 3 50`' (enter) in one go, as '`D`'(enter) signifies moveRight.

I hope I'm being clear in my question.

Comment: You should use `else if` instead of just a bunch of `if`s, it's more clear.

Comment: On the contrary, if I were to read the lines out loud, bunches of if's sounds more coherent rather than else if's. The code functions just fine as well.

Comment: It is semantically different though, if you use `else if` it will skip all of the rest of the `else if` tests after the matching one.

Comment: Are you suggesting it runs faster then? By skipping all the rest after the matching one, as opposed to scanning each one?

Comment: With your current code you can actually enter `P 3 50`.

Comment: @Coffee I'd expect that even the worst compiler is smart enough to optimize this to avoid unnecessary tests

Comment: @user3517150 Yes, faster. But probably not alot faster. At least we do it because it is the right thing to do.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I know that; it's about consistency and style more than anything. You aren't testing every condition, so why write your code that way?

Comment: @MattMcNabb as would I

Answer (score 0):

```
  cin >> input >> number >> position;

  if(input=='R') goto restart;
  else if(input=='X') exit(0);
  else if(input=='D') moveRight(edgeLength, board, score);
  else if(input=='S') moveDown(edgeLength,board, arrSize);
  else if(input=='A') moveLeft(edgeLength,board, arrSize);
  else if(input=='W') moveUp(edgeLength,arrSize,board);
  else 
  {
        //whatever statements for last condition;
  }
```

If you want to capture all three input at once, you can get the input first, then execute the respective actions according to the received inputs.

**Added:** Using `if` or `else-if` depends on situation. From what I see here in your code snippet, `else-if` is better than `if` because you can only have one input type everytime. Once matching character is found, (example 'D'), it will stop reading the codes below (which should be the way as it is unnecessary to check the rest of the conditions whether input is 'S' or 'A' or 'W' anymore since you already got the input). Makes your code fun slightly faster too, by preventing unnecessary checking on the conditions.

**Proof Of Concept:**

```
//Example

void fncOne()
{
    cout << "This is function one" << endl;
}

void fncTwo()
{
    cout << "This is function two" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char input;
    int number, position;
    cin >> input >> number >> position;
    if (input == 'A') fncOne();
    else if (input == 'B') fncTwo();
}
```

**Input:** `A 3 5`

**Output:** `This is function one`

Comment: I just tried your snippet, and it does work for input of 'p 3 5' now, however, singular input of a character, such as 'D', will not execute.

Comment: What datatype are you declaring "input" as?

Comment: char input; I was thinking of making it a string but left it as type character,whereas number and position are both integers

Comment: I tried, it is working.. did you use the correct input type for all 3 inputs? Like char int int

Comment: Well,    cin >> input >> number >> position; is char int int. I just tested 'D'(enter)'0'(enter)'0'(enter) to successfuly call the function moveRight. It seems as though it only accepts 3 inputs from the user

Comment: @user3517150 What other inputs does the user needs to input other than the 3? Your question only asked for 3 inputs though.

Comment: Thats all I'm asking of. If this helps, I'm recreating the puzzle game 2048, and singular character input is what designates a move, where as p 4 2048 would be a god-move and would place the number 2048 in position 4 and win the game instantly. I dont want the user to know the p command exists, so singular character input should move accordingly

Comment: So you want the program to be able to accept both Single Input and Three Inputs in one line? If that's the case, maybe you want to use a string to capture all 3 inputs, tokenize them and parse them to their respective data type.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you're going to want to get user input as a string rather than individual types.

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
```

then you'll want to parse that string based on how many words for key words/characters.

e.g.

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::stringstream stream(input); std::string temp;

while(stream >> temp)
    words.push_back(temp);

if(words.size() == 3){
    if(words[0][0] = 'p'){
        int number = std::stoi(words[1]);
        int position = std::stoi(words[2]);
        board[position] = number;
    }
    else
        ... get input again ...
}
else if(words.size() > 1){
    ... get input again ...
}
else{
    char c = words[0][0];
    if(c == 'w')
        moveUp(edgeLength,arrSize,board);
    else if(c == 's')
        moveDown(edgeLength,board, arrSize);
    else if(c == 'a')
        moveLeft(edgeLength,board, arrSize);
    else if(c == 'd')
        moveRight(edgeLength, board, score);
    else if(c == 'x')
        exit(0);
    else if(c == 'r')
        goto restart;
    else
        ... get input again ...
}
```

Of course this is only one way if you want to type one string then press enter only once.